# How can I parse this using JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to parse the results returned from a third party API.

As you can see the first block seems to be a description for the rows block columns that follow. I'm assuming this isn't standard practice as I cant find any reference to this style anywhere.
As it's not in the usual name:value pair format I'm a bit stumped.

```
{ cols: [{label: "name", type: 'string'},
    {label: "caller_id_number", type: 'string'},
    {label: "destination_number", type: 'string'},
    {label: "call_start", type: 'datetime'},
    {label: "duration", type: 'number'},
    {label: "bill_seconds", type: 'number'},
    {label: "uuid", type: 'string'},
    {label: "call_bill_total", type: 'number'},
    {label: "recorded", type: 'boolean'}],
    rows: [
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},
     {v: "1650"},
     {v: "01902321654"},
     {v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 12, 25)},
     {v: 3},
     {v: 0},
     {v: "07752f6c-b203-11e0-92e6-495a2db86d6d"},
     {v: 0},
     {v: true}]}
 ,{c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1652"},{v: "034534514"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 11, 34)},{v: 53},{v: 27},{v: "e8fe3a06-b202-11e0-92dd-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0.05},{v: true}]},
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1650"},{v: "034534580"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 11, 34)},{v: 11},{v: 9},{v: "e8dfb9dc-b202-11e0-92dc-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0.02},{v: true}]},
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1650"},{v: "03453453600"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 11, 11)},{v: 14},{v: 9},{v: "db7efd52-b202-11e0-92d6-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0.02},{v: true}]},
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1650"},{v: "0345345947"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 9, 41)},{v: 42},{v: 21},{v: "a59314bc-b202-11e0-92c7-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0.04},{v: true}]},
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1653"},{v: "345345420"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 9, 41)},{v: 28},{v: 0},{v: "a5a953f8-b202-11e0-92c8-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0},{v: true}]},
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1650"},{v: "353453120"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 8, 52)},{v: 28},{v: 5},{v: "885515bc-b202-11e0-92bd-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0.02},{v: true}]},
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1653"},{v: "34534567"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 8, 36)},{v: 10},{v: 3},{v: "7efc86d0-b202-11e0-92b8-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0.02},{v: true}]},
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1650"},{v: "34534584"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 7, 43)},{v: 34},{v: 13},{v: "5f1cfb60-b202-11e0-92b2-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0.02},{v: true}]},
 {c:[{v: "mydomain.com"},{v: "1653"},{v: "34534534561"},{v: new Date(2011, 6, 19, 14, 6, 52)},{v: 52},{v: 0},{v: "411b3faa-b202-11e0-92ab-495a2db86d6d"},{v: 0},{v: true}]}]}
```

I've only got as far as 
`var o = JObject.Parse(results); 
var records = o.SelectToken("rows").Select(s => s).ToList();`

Ideally I'd like to pull the records back into a class such as

```
public class CallDetailRecord
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String CallerIdNumber { get; set; }
    public String DestinationNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CallStart { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public String Uuid { get; set; }
    public Decimal CallBillTotal { get; set; }
    public bool Recorded { get; set; }
}
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I found out today the data was produced using [The Google Data Visualisation API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html)
Makes a lot more sense all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your sample data is not strictly valid JSON, your attempt to parse it was pretty close.

The layout that you're seeing is sometimes used by some parties who believe that the size of their result sets could be improved (decreased) by aliasing the field names. Unfortunately it isn't as straightforward to work with this, but you can pivot the items back into objects.

My preference in these cases is to use the `dynamic` keyword and `ExpandoObject`s. You can use a class if you like, as the bulk of the work of creating an object happens in the final `Select()` below and you can rewrite it to map the **v** element sets into fields of a class instead of an `ExpandoObject`. The syntax to access a field is the same, as you can see by the snippet at the end that writes all the values to the Console.

Note that I've written a helper lambda to handle the case of mapping `Date()` into `DateTime()`. I'm just pointing this out as you may have a better place to put this method (an extension method on DateTime, perhaps); but there's no harm in copying and pasting it as-is into a suitable place your code.

```
using System.Dynamic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

// ... other code removed

// You already have a means that loads your pseudo-json into results
// I used a file for the sake of this example
string results = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\sample.json");

var o = JObject.Parse(results);
var headers = o.SelectToken("cols")
    .Select(x => { return new { label = x.SelectToken("label").Value<string>(), type = x.SelectToken("type").Value<string>()}; }).ToArray();
var rows = o.SelectToken("rows").Select(s => { return s.SelectToken("c");}).ToList();

Func<JConstructor, DateTime> MapAsDateTime = (s) =>
{
    // This is sloppy on my part, you should improve this as you like.
    List<int> v = new List<int>();
    foreach (JToken t in s)
    {
        v.Add(t.Value<int>());
    }
    return new DateTime(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5]);
};

IEnumerable<dynamic> finalValues = rows.Select(s =>
    {
        var innerValues = s.ToList().Select(x => { return x.SelectToken("v"); }).ToArray();
        int i = 0;
        dynamic val = new ExpandoObject();
        IDictionary<string, object> valueMap = (IDictionary<string, object>)val;
        foreach (var innerValue in innerValues)
        {
            switch (headers[i].type)
            {
                case "string":
                    // NOTE: This can be improved, you could try to match and convert GUIDs with a regex or something else.
                    valueMap[headers[i].label] = innerValue.Value<string>();
                    break;
                case "datetime":
                    valueMap[headers[i].label] = MapAsDateTime((JConstructor)innerValue);
                    break;
                case "number":
                    // NOTE: This can be improved, your specific case needs decimal to handle things like 0.25, but many others could get by with just int
                    valueMap[headers[i].label] = innerValue.Value<decimal>();
                    break;
                case "boolean":
                    valueMap[headers[i].label] = innerValue.Value<bool>();
                    break;
                default:
                    // NOTE: You will need to add more cases if they 'define' more types.
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("unhandled type \"{0}\" found in schema headers.", headers[i].type));
            }
            i++;
        }
        return val;
    });

foreach (dynamic d in finalValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}", d.name);
    Console.WriteLine("caller_id_number: {0}", d.caller_id_number);
    Console.WriteLine("destination_number: {0}", d.destination_number);
    Console.WriteLine("call_start: {0}", d.call_start);
    Console.WriteLine("duration: {0}", d.duration);
    Console.WriteLine("bill_seconds: {0}", d.bill_seconds);
    Console.WriteLine("uuid: {0}", d.uuid);
    Console.WriteLine("call_bill_total: {0}", d.call_bill_total);
    Console.WriteLine("recorded: {0}", d.recorded);
    Console.WriteLine("--");
}
```

And finally, the sample output for the very first unit of data in your sample.

```
name: mydomain.com
caller_id_number: 1650
destination_number: 01902321654
call_start: 6/19/2011 2:12:25 PM
duration: 3
bill_seconds: 0
uuid: 07752f6c-b203-11e0-92e6-495a2db86d6d
call_bill_total: 0
recorded: True
--
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff, that's certainly got me out of a pickle!
It's the field name aliasing that was throwing me so much.
Thank you so much for your time creating this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what that is, but it's not JSON.  It looks like javascript and would likely parse fine with a javascript engine.

JSON spec:  http://json.org/

Validator:  http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll definitely take a look at this, thank you.